# Angular same route navigation with params and query params

Tags: angular

I have parameters in url and in my page there is listing with pagination.
For pagination i want to use query parameters.

i am getting type  by BehaviorSubject and getting query params by activatedRoute.queryParamMap.
i have also used SameUrlNavigation: 'reload'.

Example :
/type_1,/type_1?page=2,/type_1?page=3
/type_2,/type_2?page=2,/type_2?page=3

When i have selected type 1, then select pagination is works fine.
**When i change param to type_2, then select pagination it is not working.
It is not firing queryParam change event in ActivatedRoute. **

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: If that example url is multple examples, can you split it up so it more clear. If that is the url its incorrectly formattet. Also please share the code where you set the BehaviorSubject. Though i don't think that should be required because you already have an observable from the queryParamMap. Hence a code example would help to find the issue.